# Cannot change android switch widget size

Tags: android, android-widget, android-switch

I'm having some difficulties changing the Android standard Switch width. I managed to change its height but not its width. I did something like this:

```
                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/coating_video_switch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
                    android:minWidth="40dp"
                    android:minHeight="40dp"
                    android:textSize="5sp"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:textOff="fo"
                    android:textOn="no"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
                    android:track="@drawable/track"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/coating_lbl_video_mode"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I tried to change the **switchMinWidth** 's value but nothing happens. Setting the **width** of the **widget** and **maxWidth** doesn't help because it just **"crops"** the switch meaning that the **thumb and track have the same size** but you are able to see just a part(middle) of them. I follow other threads regarding this issue which say that the **drawable elements are actually changing the width of the switch**. I've created 2 drawable elements(track and thumb png files) and **give them different sizes in pixels but still nothing happens**. I also changed the textSize value but the text never changes. What am I missing here? Thank you for your time and for any tip!

Comment: okay.first of all please remove android:minWidth and android:minHeight ...check result

Comment: removed, but still the same result

Comment: You can achieve this by RadioGroup and Radio button. Have a look on the answer given by me for the question stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button/33231991#33231991

Comment: Switch's size is controlled by it's thumb drawable